# How can I understand check point recorvery when using Kafka Direct InputDstream and stateful stream transformation?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

On yarn-cluster I use kafka directstream as input(ex.batch time is 15s),and want to aggregate the input msg in seperate userIds.
So I use stateful streaming api like `updateStateByKey` or `mapWithState`.But from the api source,I see that the `mapWithState`'s default checkpoint duration is batchduration * 10 (in my case 150 s),and in kafka directstream the partition offset is checkpointed at every batch(15 s).Actually,every dstream can set different checkpoint duration.
So, my question is:

When streaming app crashed,I restart it,the kafka offset and state stream rdd are asynchronous in checkpoint,in this case how can I keep no data lose? Or I misunderstand the checkpoint mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I keep no data lose?

Stateful streams such as `mapWithState` or `updateStateByKey` *require* you to provide a checkpoint directory because that's part of how they operate, they store the state every intermediate to be able to recover the state upon a crash.

Other than that, each `DStream` in the chain is free to request checkpointing as well, question is "do you really need to checkpoint other streams"?

If an application crashes, Spark takes all the state RDDs stored inside the checkpoint and brings then back to memory, so your data there is as good as it was the last time spark checkpointed it there. One thing to keep in my mind is, if you change your application code, **you cannot recover state from checkpoint, you'll have to delete it**. This means that if for instance you need to do a version upgrade, all data that was previously stored in the state will be gone unless you manually save it yourself in a manner which allows versioning.

Comment: thanks for reply :)   In my case,I have handled the case when app version update.But what I really want to know is that: For example,start time is 0s,batch time is 15s,mapWithState checkpoint interval is 150s.So in case that streaming app crashed at time 200s,when restart it without recompiled,the stateful stream recovery to data at 150s,and kafka offset record recovery to time at 195s.Did I lose the kafka input data at 165s,180s?If true,how can I avoid this?Thanks~

Comment: @HengSu If the checkpoint was at 150s, then when you recover, it'll start over again from 150 going forward. This means you'll likely process data that's already been processed, but that is how checkpointing works. Kafka offsets are also stored inside the checkpointed data.

Comment: @ Yuval Itzchakov Sorry,I was a little confused.Is it right that the kafka offset will be checkpointed every batch(15s)?When MapWithStateDStream recover to the data at 150s,do you mean that the kafka offset also recover to 150s other than 195s?So I didn't lose data ,just only reprocess some batches of them?

Comment: @HengSu That's correct. [Here's a quote from the docs for the direct streaming approach](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers): *Hence in this second approach, we use simple Kafka API that does not use Zookeeper. Offsets are tracked by Spark Streaming within its checkpoints. This eliminates inconsistencies between Spark Streaming and Zookeeper/Kafka)*